# unable to get value from input type 'email' field in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to get the input value from the input field of type 'email' but I am getting NaN. `value.password` is working, and I am able to get the value of the `password` field, but `document.getElementById('em-id').value` is giving me `NaN`.

Please help me to solve this problem.

My code snippet is below

```
      <div class="email-div">
        <i class="fas fa-user-shield"></i>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="em-id" placeholder="Email" min="3" max="15" 
        spellcheck="false" required="true">
      </div>
     <div class="pass-div">
       <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password" min="8" max="32" 
       spellcheck="false" required="true">
     </div>
     <div class="btn-div">
       <button class="btn" id="login-btn" v-on:click="login">LOGIN</button>
     </div>




    login: function() {
        let email = document.getElementById('em-id').value
        let password = document.getElementById('pass').value
        if(email && password) {
          console.log('email => ', + email)       //gives output Nan 
          console.log('password => ' + password)
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comma and plus created the issue. Javascript tried to convert email to number **typecasting** due to the plus before email. Either you should use comma to log 2 values or + without comma for single string.

> , +

```
   login: function() {
            let email = document.getElementById('em-id').value
            let password = document.getElementById('pass').value
            if(email && password) {
              console.log('email => '+ email)   
              console.log('password => '+ password)
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The em-id  is for an  input field that has the the type Email. .Value expects it it to be for a numerical field. You could remove value and the code should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is comma here **console.log('email => ', + email)**

```
login: function() {
        let email = document.getElementById('em-id').value
        let password = document.getElementById('pass').value
        if(email && password) {
          console.log('email => ' + email)       //gives output Nan 
          console.log('password => ' + password)
       }
    }
```